# Distribute 32bit float over 4 integers (RGBA) in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

**1.** Consider a 32bit java float `sample` in (0.0f .. 1.0f) and four 32bit java integers `r, g, b, a` each in (0 .. 255) in a vector called `RGBA`.

**2.** The `sample` variable contains normalized measurement data that I wish to present in an `ImageIcon` in the form of a heat map. The target for the final RGBA values is an integer vector that later is passed as pixel data to a java `BufferdImage`.

**3.** The constraints are that when `sample==0.0f` then `RGBA==[0,0,0,255]` with uniform distribution so that `sample==1.0f` represents `RGBA==[255,0,0,255]` and with `sample==0.5f` is represented by `RGBA==[255,255,255,255]`. The alpha channel is always 255.

**4.** So far I have used a static method by dividing the colors into three separate sections R G B while A remain static at 255. Like so

```
/* BLUE */
if ( sample <= 0.340000f ){
    localSample = (sample/(0.340000f/255.000000f));
    sourceLinearData[localIndex] = 0; // R
    sourceLinearData[localIndex+1] = 0; // G
    sourceLinearData[localIndex+2] = Math.round(localSample); // B
}
```

**5.** My questions: A) Are there any suitable java api's/libraries that would help me do this? B) If not then I ask for suggestions to a solution.

**6.** Thoughts: Since each of the R, G, B, A are in (0 .. 255) I assume I can use bytes instead of integers and then possibly shift these bytes into one variable and then extract the float that way. Though I have not had any success with this method so far.

**7.** EDIT: Adding example heat map

[image: Example heat map]

SOLVED: So, like many other things in software development, this question too holds more than a single answer. In my case I wanted the most direct route with the least amount of additional work. Because of that I decided to go with the answer given by @haraldK. This said though, if you are looking for a formal solution with more control, precision and flexibility, the answer provided by @SashaSalauyou is the more correct one.

Comment: Note that java uses signed bytes, so you'll have to convert them back to signed integers with byte & 0xFF.

Comment: You could do r = sample * 255; That would make a blue-to-red gradient, but it wouldn't be white at 0.5.

Comment: If I understand well, 1.0 is red, 0.5 is white, and 0.0 is black. If it is so, it is hard to imagine what the linear color gradient looks like. What colors are actually used for the heat map ?

Comment: @Emd4600: Yes, I think I understand what you mean. Though in this case I am looking to find a gradient which is white at 0.5f.

Comment: @SirDarius: You are correct. The heat map will show the distribution of energy deposited at a specific position in a medium. I will attempt to add an example image above.

Comment: UPDATE: I was not allowed to embed the image but a link is available above.

Comment: @Peter I fixed the image for you. If someone with better SO markdown-fu than me could just make it slightly smaller, it would be great. ;-)

Comment: PS: I think you want to work in HSV color space. Your scale above is similar to 0-75% hue, with constant saturation and brightness.

Comment: @haraldK: Thank you for the edit and I will take that suggestion to heart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment above. This doesn't give *exactly* the colors in the map above, but it is pretty close, and extremely simple:

```
float sample = ...; // [0...1]
float hue = (1 - sample) * .75f; // limit hue to [0...0.75] to avoid color "loop"
int rgb = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1, 1).getRGB();
```

If you want darker tints in "edges" of the scale, you could use a sine function to compute the brightness, for example:

```
float hue = (1 - sample) * .75f;
float brightness = .5f + (float) Math.sin(Math.PI * sample) / 2;
int rgb = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1, brightness).getRGB();
```

Comment: It won't produce dark-red and dark-blue, but if they are not strictly necessary, this approach is better.

Comment: Yes, the HSV space "loops". Fixed the range from red to blue/purple. But you are right, the colors are still not exactly like in the image (I do state that in the answer).

Comment: @haraldK: Can you elaborate on how the rgb value in your example is used in a situation where I have to specify each value of r g and b separatly?

Comment: @Peter You mean, you want to split the RGB value to an array of {R, G, B}? You could do something like `int[]  rgbs = new int[] {(rgb >> 16) & 0xff, (rgb >> 8) & 0xff, rgb & 0xff}`. But the packed int RGB format is generally more useful, when working with images (ie. `BufferedImage`s) in Java.

Comment: @haraldK: It seems this is the most direct method. However the order of colors is incorrect. I added a special case for threshold values such as below 0.0nnn in order to avoid a mostly red image. Is it possible to invert the data somehow?

Comment: @Peter Inverted the values now, to have the low values map to blue and high to red.

Comment: @haraldK: Oh... right.  I see... ;) It was way too simple!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest some kind of interpolation in a path that value from 0 to 1 performs in 3D color space:

```
// black: c = 0.0
// blue:  c = 0.3 
// white: c = 0.5
// red:   c = 1.0
// add more color mappings if needed, keeping c[] sorted

static float[] c = {0.0, 0.3, 0.5, 1.0};
static int[] r =   {  0,   0, 255, 255}; // red components
static int[] g =   {  0,   0, 255,   0}; // green components
static int[] b =   {  0, 255, 255,   0}; // blue components

public int[] getColor(float f) {
    int i = 0;
    while (c[i] < f) 
       i++;
    if (i == 0) 
       return new int[] {r[0], g[0], b[0]};

    // interpolate
    float k = (f - c[i-1]) / (c[i] - c[i-1]);
    return new int[] {
         Math.round((r[i] - r[i-1]) * k + r[i-1]),
         Math.round((g[i] - g[i-1]) * k + g[i-1]),
         Math.round((b[i] - b[i-1]) * k + b[i-1])
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: You missed the semicolons on the array declarations. Besides that, it works correctly.

Comment: @Sasha: Are you able to view the example image I posted above (matlab generation of same thing)? I am sure the solution you provide is accurate but I am not getting the expected results. I assume I am not adding additional colors to c[] correctly. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: @Peter I provided mapping arrays (`c`, `r`, `g` and `b`) for colors and values you provided in your question. You can change them as you need to achieve desired result.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: Noted. I will keep this post updated.

Comment: as I see in picture, value 0.5 should produce green (0, 255, 0), but you firstly said it must be white (255, 255, 255) etc.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, two questions:
1) Could you explain how the vector c works? Is it used to find some kind of boundary?
2) What would I need to change in your example in order to distribute the color space such as in the image above?

Comment: @Peter in `c[]` we put intermediate normalized values from 0 to 1, in `r[]`, `g[]` and `b[]` we put values of corresponding color components in indexes that correspond with values in `c[]`.

Comment: @Peter for example, if `c[2] == 0.35` and you want to associate 0.35 with green (0, 255, 0), put 0 into `r[2]`, 255 into `g[2]` and 0 into `b[2]`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: Understood, thank you. I think I am almost there! What I can not seem to resolve is that there are sharp gradient changes in regions which there should not be. The distribution is not even over the entire color space (atleast it seems that way). If it helps I can reference another image generated by my program.

Comment: @Peter to make gradient smoother, add more intermediate points, I believe set of {0, 0.2, 0.35, 0.5, 0.65, 0.8, 1} will be enough.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: Your answer is the most complete answer and if I could only understand why adding more intermediate points give me an even worse image then this would be the perfect, most dynamic and complete solution. I will keep working on this.

Answer (score 0):

Lerp should do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float value = 0.5f;

    float[] red = new float[] {1.0f, 0, 0};
    float[] white = new float[] {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    float[] black = new float[] {0, 0, 0};

    if (value <= 0.5f) {
        float gradientValue = value * 2;
        int[] color = new int[] {(int) (lerp(white[0], black[0], gradientValue) * 255), (int) (lerp(white[1], black[1], gradientValue) * 255), 
                (int) (lerp(white[2], black[2], gradientValue) * 255), 255};
    } else if (value > 0.5f) {
        float gradientValue = (value + 1) / 2.0f;
        int[] color = new int[] {(int) (lerp(white[0], red[0], gradientValue) * 255), (int) (lerp(white[1], red[1], gradientValue) * 255), 
                (int) (lerp(white[2], red[2], gradientValue) * 255), 255};
    }
}

public static float lerp(float v0, float v1, float t) {
      return (1-t)*v0 + t*v1;
}
```

(the order of the lerp arguments might be different, I haven't tested)

Comment: `lerp` is linear interpolation, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I'm used to call it lerp.